# Partial distro upgrade causes gnome-shell-extensions to be incompatible?

Tags: gnome, extension, partial-upgrade

Today I did a partial upgrade through the update manager, and in the process it uninstalled gnome-3. I reinstalled gnome-3 and now I can not install any shell extensions because they are "out of date," even though I am on the same version of gnome that I was on before the update (3.4.2). Only the default extensions work, such as user-themes, dock, and places. I am trying to get the mediaplayer extension to work but I can't find a version anywhere that is compatible. Can I fix this in the source code of the extension and build it myself?

Answer (score 2):

#### The OP found the answer (originally posted in question):

I found the solution. The problem was that the partial upgrade updated many of the dependencies for gnome3, and those dependencies are not backwards-compatible. This is why it made every extension act as if it were out of date. I used a package called ppa-purge to remove all third party packages and return dependencies to the latest versions required. Here where the steps I took:

```
#WARNING: This will remove ALL third party ppa's!!! 
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell-extensions-*
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
sudo apt-get purge gnome-tweak-tool
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
```

After this, I reinstalled gnome3 the normal way.

```
sudo apt-get add ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```